# Change dbase table alias

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, table, dbf

How can I change the alias of a dbase table without completley renaming the file?

I've tried right clicking the the file, opening properties, and changing the alias, but it will not allow me to edit the alias or name this way. 
Any suggestions?[image]

Comment: Do you have write access to the dBase file?

Comment: dBase is a file which for that parameter is read only.

Answer (score 1):

As my comment noted, dBase is a file which for that parameter is read only.  So you cannot change the alias name of a dBase file.  If you want to use change alias parameter you will need to import the dBase table into a geodatabase.